# Asp.net mvc in SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I created a `ASP.net MVC 5` project in Visual Studio 2013, running in a Windows 8.1 Pro.

I've been ask to put my project on a `SharePoint`, but I don't quite know how it's done.
i tried creating a `SharePoint` project on my Visual Studio but it won't let me since I don't have `SharePoint` installed, and when I try to install SharePoint Foundation 2010 or 2013 it complains I don't have Windows Server.

How do I make my project work on a `SharePoint`?

Comment: Maybe helpful to search first: [Installing SP on Windows 8](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2014/08/21/guest-blog-by-jonas-nilsson-install-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-7-8-8-1.aspx). But you do not need to install a SharePoint, you can also create an app with ASP.net MVC an deploy it to your office365 SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to put your project on sharepoint? Cool!

In your case you definetly want to get your own SharePoint environment. To develop Apps (or Add-ins as they are called today) you mainly use Client-side code and techniques. This also means that you need to handle the SharePoint resources with asyncronous programming. Its very powerful, But that is not what you are asking for.

I would set up an SharePoint 2013 Foundation environment since its free and will very much deliver the capabilities you are after. Keep in mind though that SharePoint is a HUGE system that requires some understanding to be utilized.

I made a blogpost a while back where i Installed Win Server 2012 R2 on a external disk, this example works with SharePoint if you just want to debug your project on a SharePoint server. Check it out here: http://bayerlein.se/install-windows-server-on-external-hdd-with-the-help-of-virtual-box/

This solution will of course also require that you install your development program in the same environment.

Good luck//Kodz

Answer (score 0):

It really depends upon what you want to do. Do you need to create a provider hosted app with MVC for SharePoint 2013? In that case, you might succeed with including the necessary references and tooling code (but you still might lack the app manifest project). Technically your project won't run on SharePoint but uses the SharePoint API.

If you need to create an SharePoint solution package, you need a SharePoint development install (and as SharePoint doesn't install on all client OS, your best way is going virtual with a SharePoint development VM). Keep in mind that developing solution packages is a different kind of trade than developing for MVC, so start with a Pluralsite course or some other kind of training.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a SharePoint app. You can use VS2015 with SP online so that you don't need to install SP locally. Create a trial o365 account and enable developer site on it. You can deploy your app on the developer site then. If you have developer site from you client instead of using sp online you can use that too.

Once your app works you can create package to deploy on the SharePoint environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think right now, the best way for you would be signing up as Microsoft Office 365 Developer and having a trial of the 365 cloud where you can setup sharepoint 2013 site collection and also develop apps using their tool NAPA.
These days they are calling apps "SharePoint Add-ins"
[NAPA and SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220038.aspx)

I would also suggest you take a look at this article:
[SharePoint 2013 Developing Apps vs. Solutions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/03/25/sharepoint-2013-development-apps-versus-solutions.aspx)